# which sql query is the best

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I need a "search" function in my application, what is the best way to do this in SQL Server?

1. Create a query with 1 large where-clause containing all the columns using an OR statement and creating 1 index containing all the columns

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE CustomerNumber LIKE '%' + @SearchValue +'%'
OR LastName LIKE '%' + @SearchValue +'%'
OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @SearchValue +'%'
OR
```

2. Create seperate queries for each column using UNION and create an index for each column

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer 
WHERE CustomerNumber LIKE '%' + @SearchValue +'%'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM Customer
WHERE LastName LIKE '%' + @SearchValue +'%'
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM Customer
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @SearchValue +'%'
```

I've read that indexes don't support the OR statement? So solution 2 is the only correct one?

This may seem a very easy question for some of you, but I'm trying to understand "why" I need to do this, so any background info is always welcome.

Comment: They may/may not return the same result depending on the table data. (Duplicates removed by UNION.)

Comment: Where did you read that indexes don't support `OR`?

Comment: If you have two working queries and you want to know which is best, testing is often a good way to know that. Indexes supporting or not supporting OR (the database does support it) is irrelevant to this question because your search terms can't be normal index searched anyway (full text indexes would be good here) because they are not sargable due to the wildcards. This is important to read up on and learn why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is optimal, but the first is a bit better.  It only scans the data once and the evaluation of `like` is short-circuited for matches to the first or second condition.  In addition, `union` is going to incur overhead for removing duplicates.

If you really want performance, then investigate the full text indexing options provided by your database.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I investigated the Full-Text search but it seems there is no equivalent to Like '%xxx%'. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

It is not generally true for any rdb that `OR` conditions cannot be optimized; AFAIK skipping indexes are implemented by most RDBs, which means multiple-range conditions can be optimized. In your case however, because your `LIKE` conditions start with `%` and are thus not prefix matches, they cannot be optimized by indexes, because they are not range conditions. Even so, you should use the `OR` composition: it is easier to read, true to the intent of the query and it is very likely that the `UNION` query will do multiple table scans, one for every subquery while the OR query will likely do a single scan, which should be faster. I say "likely" because with an ideal query optimizer, all equivalent queries should be resolved to the best execution plan - in this case, a single scan. But optimizers are far from "ideal". So while with different rdb's YMMV, go with the `OR` query.

With a query like this though, if you are searching for words, you should consider using full-text indexes if available, and they are available in most rdbs but with different query syntaxes. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9136/sql-server-full-text-indexes/

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the `ORIDX` operation in DB2. +1

Answer (score 0):

Both the queries are in a way for not optimum performance.

for option 1 - the or is scanning many possibilities and it is not better way to do.. you should actually have string indexing to combine all options together.

options 2 - this is slower then first option as it is doing multiple select options.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry about indexes.

None of those queries will use any index. They'll perform Full Table Scans anyway since the search patterns start with `%`.

The first one will perform a single Full Table Scan, while the second one will perform three. Therefore the first one will be faster.

Also, keep in mind the second query will return slightly different result set since it removes duplicates.

Comment: The queries can still use an index _scan_, but not a _seek_. That could reduce the physical I/O significantly compared to a table scan depending on the size of a row versus the size of the columns being searched and the number of matching rows.

Comment: @HABO The selected list of columns is `*`, so the use of a covering index is not useful. An index range scan is also not useful, since there's no start or stop conditions. It needs to scan all the rows anyway.